# Add Infamous Condition to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple table named Transaction_Body

| ID | ItemsID | DateX | ItemAmount | totalcost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-06-08 | -1 | -500 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-06-07 | -2 | -1000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-06-07 | 1 | 400 |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-06-03 | 2 | 800 |

Please notice that I have some values < 0

I have this simple query here

```
select 
    SUM(T.totalcost) / SUM(T.ItemAmount) as AVG
FROM Transaction_Body T
Where T.ItemsID = 1 and T.DateX <='2023-06-07' 
group by T.ItemsID
```

This code gives me the average but I want to add a condition beside these conditions up

(( If 'ItemsAmount' < 0 in 'DateX' = '2023-06-07' Just ignore it from calculation ))

Comment: Why not just add `and ItemAmount > 0` to the `where` clause?

Comment: Becasue i need All itemsAmount Exept that < 0 in datex = '2023-06-07'

Comment: Whats an "infamous" condition?

Comment: `Where DateX < '2023-06-07' or (DateX = '2023-06-07' and itemAmount >= 0)`

Comment: I would go with the `where` filter then @AhmedSaif it will be more efficient than scanning all rows regardless or an anti-semi join filter.

Comment: @DaleK infamy infamy they all got it in for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query: -

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.ItemAmount < 0 AND T.DateX = '2023-06-07' THEN 0 ELSE T.totalcost END) /
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.ItemAmount < 0 AND T.DateX = '2023-06-07' THEN 0 ELSE T.ItemAmount END) AS AVG
FROM Transaction_Body T
WHERE T.ItemsID = 1 AND T.DateX <= '2023-06-07'
GROUP BY T.ItemsID;
```

Comment: What infamous about it, @AhmedSaif ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(T.totalcost) / SUM(T.ItemAmount) as AVG
FROM Transaction_Body T
WHERE T.ItemsID = 1
    AND T.DateX <= '2023-06-07'
    /* Exclude rows where ItemAmount < 0 on DateX = '2023-06-07' */
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Transaction_Body T2
        WHERE T2.ItemsID = T.ItemsID
            AND T2.DateX = '2023-06-07'
            AND T2.ItemAmount < 0
    )
GROUP BY T.ItemsID;
```

This subquery with the NOT EXISTS clause is used to exclude rows where 'ItemsID' is the same as the outer query's 'ItemsID', 'DateX' is '2023-06-07', and 'ItemAmount' is less than 0. If any such row exists, it will be ignored in the calculation.